# Kubernetes- Minion cannot talk to master

Tags: kubernetes, openstack, coreos

We have deployed Kubernetes using OpenStack Heat on CoreOS. The below command of fetching nodes does not get any results:

```
kubectl -s http://<Master FIP>:8080 get nodes
```

On looking at the minion, we saw that kubelet cannot talk to the master. kubelet on minion has these [errors](https://gist.github.com/voa808/f5e6414725a20c196887f0584b90adee).

In the master node, the container - hyperkube controller displays the below error (10.0.0.4 is the private IP for the master):

```
W0909 17:42:34.411146       1 request.go:347] Field selector: v1 - serviceaccounts - metadata.name - default: need to check if this is versioned correctly.
I0909 17:42:34.465422       1 endpoints_controller.go:322] Waiting for pods controller to sync, requeuing service default/kubernetes
W0909 17:43:04.249935       1 nodecontroller.go:433] Unable to find Node: 10.0.0.4, deleting all assigned Pods. 
E0909 17:43:04.284611       1 nodecontroller.go:434] pods "kube-apiserver-10.0.0.4" not found
```

I am not sure how should we debug this. Could someone please suggest what could be wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by making the hyperkube version same on master and minion nodes. In our case, we updated it to v1.3.4. (Used gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.3.4)